# How do I show an online webpage on my desktop?

Tags: website

I Need This Page on My Desktop:

> http://onlineclock.net/

Saving the page source doesn't work...Please help me.

Comment: You mean you want to have the clock working on your computer right?

Comment: yeah..that's what I want

Answer (score 6):

If you're using Windows XP you can do this via Active Desktop:

1. Open the Control Panel.
2. Open the Display icon.
3. Click the Desktop tab.
4. Click the Customize Desktop button.
5. Click the Web tab in the Desktop Items window.

[image]

*Windows Vista has replaced the Active Desktop with Windows Sidebar (Now Called Windows Desktop Gadgets starting with Windows 7) , which also allows components to be added to the desktop.*

Comment: That brings up a good question though... is there any desktop gadget for V/7 which essentially runs an iframe hosting a user-specified URL? 
I didn't see one with a quick google, but I guess it could be useful.