# How do I show an online webpage on my desktop (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows-10, website

Lately I was looking into how to show time/timer countdown from an online webpage on my desktop. I visited this question below, it is the most relevant one, but it is more than 10 years old. Is there a solution for Windows 10?

[How do I show an online webpage on my desktop?](https://superuser.com/questions/76601/how-do-i-show-an-online-webpage-on-my-desktop)

Answer (score 2):

Use [lively](https://rocksdanister.github.io/lively/)! it's a free and open-source software for live wallpapers in windows 10. it has a feature to set a webpage as wallpaper. you can find a tutorial [here](https://www.howto-connect.com/set-live-website-as-wallpaper-windows-10/)

there are other apps like [WallpaperWebPage](https://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/WallpaperWebPage.shtml), but I don't recommend them since they are not simple and flawless like lively. also, there is an active community behind the lively and they continually updating the app

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is the commercial
[Plastuer](https://plastuer.com/) ($5):

> Plastuer is a Windows application for setting GIFs,
> Videos, and WebPages as your wallpaper